# plot_decision_boundary() somehow not giving any output

Tags: python, keras, data-visualization

so I have been attempting to view the decision boundary for my network and for some reason when i run it it doesn't give me any output.
i took the function from [here](https://jonchar.net/notebooks/Artificial-Neural-Network-with-Keras/)

it doesn't give any error, it just ends the run.

```
    # Fit the model also history to map the model
history = model.fit(X, Y,validation_split=0.30, epochs=10, batch_size=1000, verbose= 1)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)

def plot_decision_boundary(X, y, model, steps=1000, cmap='Paired'):
    """
    Function to plot the decision boundary and data points of a model.
    Data points are colored based on their actual label.
    """
    cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap)

    # Define region of interest by data limits
    xmin, xmax = X[:,0].min() - 1, X[:,0].max() + 1
    ymin, ymax = X[:,1].min() - 1, X[:,1].max() + 1
    steps = 1000
    x_span = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, steps)
    y_span = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, steps)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_span, y_span)

    # Make predictions across region of interest
    labels = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Plot decision boundary in region of interest
    z = labels.reshape(xx.shape)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.contourf(xx, yy, z, cmap=cmap, alpha=0.5)

    # Get predicted labels on training data and plot
    train_labels = model.predict(X)
    ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=y, cmap=cmap, lw=0)

    return fig, ax


plot_decision_boundary(X, Y, model, cmap='RdBu')
```

i havn't really done many changes to the function.
what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `plot_decision_boundary()` constructs a `fig` and an `ax` object which are returned at the end. In your code there is nothing to take up these objects when they are returned. Just because a function returns fig and ax that does not mean, they are automatically drawn.

Solution is simple, just call

```
plt.show()
```

after calling the decision boundary function.
This part is often omitted in example codes. I believe it is because there are several ways to generate the window and show the plot (you could also want to save it directly to file in which case you wouldn't need the show() statement).